# Python: How to update plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a graphic with matplotlib using subplot, so

```
self.figure = Figure()
self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
.
.
.
t = np.arange(0.0, 30.0, 0.01)
self.axes.plot(t)
```

Now, when I press a button I want to update the graph, but it seems that I cannot just use self.axes.plot(t) inside the function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The calls to `Axes` functions do not automatically trigger a re-draw (unlike the `plt` functions).  You just need to add a

```
self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

call.

Answer (score 1):

Try `self.figure.canvas.draw()` if you want to force the figure to be updated.